[UIInputSwitcherView selectedInputMode]crash on iOS 18.1
0 CoreFoundation __exceptionPreprocess + 164

1 libobjc.A.dylib objc_exception_throw + 88

2 CoreFoundation -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:] + 0

3 UIKitCore -[UIInputSwitcherView selectedInputMode] + 116

4 UIKitCore -[UIInputSwitcherView didSelectItemAtIndex:] + 148

5 UIKitCore -[UIKeyboardMenuView selectItemAtPoint:] + 92

6 UIKitCore -[UIInputSwitcherView buttonPressed:withEvent:location:isLocationInsideViewHitArea:isForDictation:tapAction:] + 1040

7 UIKitCore -[UISystemKeyboardDockController dictationItemButtonWasPressed:withEvent:isRunningButton:] + 660

8 UIKitCore -[UISystemKeyboardDockController keyboardDockView:didPressDockItem:withEvent:] + 448

9 UIKitCore -[UIKeyboardDockView _dockItemButtonWasTapped:withEvent:] + 120

this crash happen on iOS 18.1,crash reason is '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index  beyond bounds [0 .. 2]',so how can i fix this crash,anyone now
